# Kafka JDBC source connector performance issue - permenant full usage of CPUs

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, hana

I am using kafka cluster consists of 3 zookeepers, 3 brokers, 3 connect instances and schema-registry.

broker and connect instances are aws ec2 c5.2xlarge machines with 8 cores and 16GB of RAM.

kafka and java versions:

```
kafka-dump-log --version
5.5.3-ccs (Commit:82571ebfbfc60c9c)

java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So I post 25 [SAP HANA](https://github.com/SAP/kafka-connect-sap) source connectors, each connectors consumes one table from the database and write it into one topic with one partition.

The problem is that I am not getting all tables consumesd and the CPUs seem always to be working on full capacity. If I turn off all the connectors and post one of those connectors which didn't consume anything earlier, eventually it will do it after 1 hour or so.

here is an example of configuration of one of those connectors:

```json
{
    "connector.class": "com.sap.kafka.connect.source.hana.HANASourceConnector",
    "connection.password": "xxxx",
    "dialect.name": "SapHanaDatabaseDialect",
    "connection.user": "xxx",
    "numeric.mapping": "none",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sap://xxx",

    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "schema_url",
    "value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "schema_url",

    "transforms": "castBinary,AddNamespace,TimestampConverter",
    "transforms.castBinary.type": "com.costumecast.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value",
    "transforms.castBinary.spec": "SOME_COLUMN:string",

    "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
    "transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "string",
    "transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "SOME_COLUMN_2",

    "transforms.AddNamespace.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
    "transforms.AddNamespace.schema.name": "com.agcs.kafka.avro.TEST_TOPIC",

    "tasks.max": "1",
    "mode": "incrementing",

    "topics": "TEST_TOPIC",
    "TEST_TOPIC.table.name": "\"database\".\"view.test_table\"",
    "TEST_TOPIC.incrementing.column.name": "SOME_COLUMN_2",

    "batch.max.rows": "0",
    "TEST_TOPIC.poll.interval.ms": "144000000"

  }
```

the /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties file has nothing special:

```
bootstrap.servers=xxxx:xxxx,xxxx:xxxx,xxxx:xxxx

group.id=STREAMS_SINK_dev_connect_cluster

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://xxxx:xxxx
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://xxxx:xxxx

config.storage.topic=_STREAMS_SINK_dev_connect_configs
offset.storage.topic=_STREAMS_SINK_dev_connect_offsets
status.storage.topic=_STREAMS_SINK_dev_connect_statuses

config.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3

plugin.path=/usr/share/java/
# Connect worker
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=xxx
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="xxx" \
  password="xxx";

# Embedded producer for source connectors
producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=xxx
producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
producer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="xxx" \
  password="xxx";

# Embedded consumer for sink connectors
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=xxx
consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="xxx" \
  password="xxx";
```

here is a screenshot of the usage of CPUs on the connectors.

[image]

My question is why the performance is so poor? (the tables in the source database are not huge, all less than 1M records) are 25 connectors too much in this context? or did I overseen some parameter in the configuration. Also, why doesn't the CPU usage calm down when there is no more data to fetch in 22 tables and the other 3 tables just doing nothing?

would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Is the high CPU usage only during snapshotting or post it? How soon are you polling for each event : poll.interval.ms ? How many records do you expect on an average per second per connector? If the use case tolerates it, you should specify a larger batch and a larger poll.

Comment: no, the high CPU usage is constant. poll.interval.ms =144000000 (40 hours) "batch.max.rows": "0" means collect everything in the table (thre are less than 1M records in each table)

Comment: If you increase logging on the Connect workers do you get an indication of what they are busy doing? You can target particular loggers, e.g. `curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/admin/loggers/com.sap -d '{"level": "TRACE"}'`

Comment: when I send the request I get `["com.sap","com.sap.kafka.client.hana.HANAJdbcClient","com.sap.kafka.connect.source.hana.HANASourceTask","com.sap.kafka.connect.source.querier.IncrColTableQuerier","com.sap.kafka.utils.ExecuteWithExceptions$","com.sap.kafka.utils.hana.HANAJdbcTypeConverter$"]` back. ButI dont get any TRACE messages in log files. Only info ` flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:447)` and `XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 111770ms.` mostly